# How to Grep second word in config file using parameter?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Currently I am building one script to grep region records in the config file based on parameter and then I am creating a text file with that output and I am reading the source file path in that output file. Now I need to pass one more parameter like module based upon that it has to create a text file.

My **script**:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_CONF="./test.properties"

#input region name
region="$1"
echo $region
cwd=$(pwd)
calu=$(grep $region test.properties > ab.txt)

IFS=$'\n'

#loop to read the config one line at a time
while read p; do
    echo $p

    a=($(echo "$p" | tr '|' '\n'))
    echo "Region is:" "${a[0]}"
    echo "path is:""${a[3]}"
    path="${a[3]}"
    #remove white space before path
    echo $cwd
    NO_LEAD_SPACE="$(echo -e $path | tr -d '[:space:]')"
    echo "path is:"$NO_LEAD_SPACE
    # change to path spacified in the config file
    sh -c 'cd $NO_LEAD_SPACE && echo "in the subshell" && echo $pwd && echo "exit subshell" && exec pwd'
    echo $cwd
    echo "--------------------"
done < ab.txt

echo "abc"
```

My **config file**:

```
region | Module |country code | filepath |filename


APJ | WDMD | MYS |/c/Users/vattikun/desktop | MYS*ADPGV*.XML
APJ | WDED | EUR|/c/Users/vattikun/desktop/Payroll Support | EUR*ADPGV*.XML

APJ | WDMD | RER|/c/Users/vattikun/desktop/Payroll Support | RER*ADPGV*.XML

APJ | WDJD | EYZ|/c/Users/vattikun/desktop/Payroll Support | EYZ*ADPGV*.XML


EMA | WDMD | AUS|/c/Users/vattikun/desktop | AUS*ADPGV*.XML
EMA | WDMD | AYS| /c/Users/vattikun/desktop | AYS*ADPGV*.XML

AMS | WDMD |ITI| /c/Users/vattikun/desktop | ITI*ADPGV*.XML
AMS |WDMD |AYS| /c/Users/vattikun/desktop | AYS*ADPGV*.XML

ETIME | WDMD |ADP /c/Users/vattikun/desktop | ADP_WDET_JOBCODE*.XML
ETIME | WDMD |AEP| /c/Users/vattikun/desktop | AEP_WDET_JOBCODE*.XML
```

Comment: It is unclear what the result should look like given the data that you show.

Comment: Your `grep $region test.properties` will match lines you don't want. For example, if `region=XML`, all of the entries will match. A better version is `grep "^ *${region}\\>" test.properties`.
And `sh -c 'cd $NO_LEAD_SPACE && ...'` won't work because the single quotes don't interpolate the variable into the command, and NO_LEAD_SPACE isn't exported. It would work better to use `(cd $NO_LEAD_SPACE && ...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question you asked, start your search expression with a pattern that will skip one field:

```
module="$2"
/bin/grep "^[^|]*| *${module}\\>" test.properties
```

To break that down:

```
^      Start of line
[^|]*  0 or more non-separator characters
|      A field separator
 *     0 or more spaces
${module}  Switch from single- to double-quotes to interpolate variable name
\\>    End of a word ("\\>" becomes '\>' when shell parses it)
```

But you're better off using something like `awk` or `perl`:

```
awk -F' *\\| *' -v module="$module" '$2 == module' test.properties
```

In the long run it might be better to use a well-known format like CSV and tools meant to work with it.